# AngularJS link to database

Tags: php, angularjs

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="rjtApp">
<head>
<title>PHP MySQL API Consumed with AngularJS</title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="GetUsers">

<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users"><td>{{ user.name }}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</tfoot></tfoot>
</table>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

api.php (this connection has no problem i tested.)

```
<?php

        // set up the connection variables
        $db_name  = 'air';
        $hostname = '127.0.0.1';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '123456';

        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

        // a query get all the records from the users table
        $sql = 'SELECT USER_NAME FROM air_users LIMIT 1';

        // use prepared statements, even if not strictly required is good practice
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

        // execute the query
        $stmt->execute();

        // fetch the results into an array
        $result = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

        // convert to json
        $json = json_encode( $result );

        // echo the json string
        echo $json;
?>
```

data.js

```
alert("this is connect");

var app = angular.module("rjtApp", []);

app.controller("GetUsers", function($scope, $http)

{

  function getProject(){

      $http.get("api.php").success(function(data){

        $scope.projects = data; //the data are stored in projects

 });

};

});

getProject();
```

My intention is to make a live validation to check database name exited, but I cannot even figure how to connecting AngularJS to database, what I have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your big issue here is that you are using $http.post instead of $http.get. Post is designed for submitting changes and new objects (think submitting a form), while get is designed for grabbing output.

So, you should be able to change

```
$http.post("api.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.projects = data; //the data are stored in projects
});
```

to

```
$http.get("api.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.projects = data; //the data are stored in projects
});
```

This will store the output of loading api.php (as if you visited the website yourself rather than in code) in projects. A useful debug tip is to put

```
alert(JSON.stringify(varname))
```

in your code if you wish to debug. This will pop up an alert containing the JSON contents of your variable as a string. In your case this would be:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.projects)).
```

I apologize for any code formatting issues. I'm new to the stack overflow system.

Comment: I wish but still no luck , And welcome to stack overflow , everything is awesome here.

Comment: Thanks user3233074! I looked at your code again and noticed a couple of things. First, you call your controller GetUser in the JavaScript and GetUsers in the HTML. So you just need to match the names to be able to use the controller itself. Second, you need to close the controller (you are missing the '});' at the end). After those two changes, an alert placed in getProject() pops up when the page loads. I'd make these changes and see if you get your data from the database. Let me know how it works. Oh, and here's the plunker I used if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/.

Comment: i changed what you told me , but i still dont get the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getProject` from outside the controller, so it is undefined out there (it is local to the controller). So move that call inside:

```
alert("this is connect");

var app = angular.module("rjtApp", []);

app.controller("GetUsers", function($scope, $http)

{

    function getProject() {

        $http.get("api.php").success(function(data) {

            $scope.projects = data; //the data are stored in projects

        });

    };
    getProject(); // moved this line

});
```

Then, the `$http` service should run. Technically, you should be using a `GET` request, but it will still work the same way with `POST`. I do want to point out that you are not currently using `projects` anywhere in your page - so you will only see the data in the network console.